# How to initialise a matrix only when calling a function?

Tags: c++, matrix, initialization

I'm wondering if I can do this: create a matrix and only initialise its size when calling a function:

```
#ifndef OCCUPANCY_GRID_H
#define OCCUPANCY_GRID_H
#include <math.h>

class OccupancyGrid{

public:

    void update_cell_value(double x, double y, double status) {
        matrix[x_origin+x][y_origin+y]=status;
    }

    void initialize_map(){
        grid_size=100;
        x_origin=grid_size/2;
        y_origin=grid_size/2;
    }

private:
    int grid_size;
    int x_origin;
    int y_origin;
    int const map[grid_size][grid_size] = {-1};
};

#endif
```

Is there any better way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: "Dynamic memory allocation" is the key word you should google. vector is a class that'll do that for you, but it is VERY important to understand using malloc/free (c way) or new[]/delete[] (c++ way).

Comment: @IdeaHat: Indeed. It's important to understand both how it works, and why you shouldn't try to do it yourself in normal circumstances.

Comment: @MikeSeymour +1 exactly, sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: like this:

vector< vector<int> > grid;

How do I initialise it then? I was looking for it online but do I really have to do a cycle?

Comment: @Carollour: Initialise it in the constructor's initialiser list with `grid(grid_size, vector<int>(grid_size))`. Unless you want to defer initialisation until you call a function, in which case a loop is probably the least bad option.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::vector<std::vector<T>>`. Ideally you would initialise it in the constructor but if you must initialize it later do so in a loop. For example:

```
class OccupancyGrid {
public:    
    void initialize_matrix(unsigned size){
        matrix.resize(size);
        for(auto& v : matrix)
            v.resize(size);
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> matrix;
};
```

Or [Boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/multi_array/doc/).

Comment: Thank you!

What does this mean:

    auto& v : matrix

?
Does it go over every column?

Comment: Yes, well it depends on your definition of "row" vs "column", I would have said row, but it loops over every "subvector" in `matrix`, yes. See [range-based for loops](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).